# Tableau case when statement - invalid syntax (missing identifier)

Tags: syntax-error, case, tableau-api

I've written:

```
case when [count_total_cre] <= 75 then (sum([count_total_cre])*15) else 0 end
```

This works in SQL.

I'm getting the following error when I try to add a Tableau calculated field:

*Syntax error (maybe you are missing an identifier)*

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tableau's calculation language doesn't allow for range comparison operators in case statements.  You need to use an if statement here.

```
if sum([count_total_cre]) <= 75 then (sum([count_total_cre])*15) else 0 end
```

Notice as well you have to either use a single value or aggregate expression on both sides.  The following would also be valid:

```
if [count_total_cre] <= 75 then [count_total_cre]*15 else 0 end
```

Which one you use depends on your ultimate goal.

And in case you were curious, this is what the case format would be in Tableau:

```
case [Sales]
when 75 then [Sales]*15
when xx then yy
else zz
end
```

Comment: Great answer. Just adding Tableau doc for reference: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_logical.htm